# Uses matches to match a whole word

Tags: java, regex

Researching another post, I found a good way of matching on a whole word.
The following matches for the hardcoded word "the"

```
String text = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";  
System.out.println(text.matches(".*\\bthe\\b.*"));
```

I want to make this a little more complicated. I want to match on the word that the user enters.
So if I setup

```
String userInput;
```

and validate it etc. etc.
How do I modify the above matches so it validates on the whole word that is contained in the String userInput?
Thanks

Comment: hmm.. that makes it really complicated.

Comment: Are you really asking how to build a regex dynamically?

Comment: `and validate it etc. etc.` what does this mean? You will get strange results if you use the word boundry assertion. Also, how do you know what you matched when you match the whole line/string?

Answer (score 3):

The obvious approach is to try this. I think it will work.

```
System.out.println(text.matches(".*\\b" + userInput + "\\b.*"));
```

Comment: doah... you beat me :-)

Comment: Hi. This works ok if I just do  String text = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";   but it is giving me a problem if I need to do    String text = new Scanner( new File("userFile.txt") ).useDelimiter("\\A").next(); When I printf text it *looks* like it has exactly the same text. Any ideas of what I can do to make the regex more general? or other ideas? thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Maybe you should post a new question explaining your new problem.